# Limit selection of a link div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two different fields, (image below)
the divs have the same and different css class,
I need to select only one, instead of one in each field.
when selecting one field, the other is disabled.

code:

````
<div class="wc-pao-addon-container  wc-pao-addon wc-pao-addon-PRODUTO" data-product-name="PRODUTO">
    <label for="addon-24177-PRODUTO" class="wc-pao-addon-name" data-addon-name="TIPO" data-has-per-person-pricing="" data-has-per-block-pricing="">PRODUTO<span class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-price">TIPO 1</span></label>
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-24177-TIPO-1">
            <a href="#" class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch" data-value="TIPO 1" data-price="<span class=&quot;wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-price&quot;>TIPO 1 </span>">
                <img src="image.jpg">
            </a>
            <select class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-select wc-pao-addon-field" name="addon-24177-PRODUTO">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="flat_fee" value="TIPO 1" data-label="TIPO 1">TIPO 1</option>
            </select>
        </p>
</div>

Field 2:
<div class="wc-pao-addon-container  wc-pao-addon wc-pao-addon-PRODUTO 2" data-product-name="PRODUTO 2">
    <label for="addon-24177-PRODUTO 2" class="wc-pao-addon-name" data-addon-name="TIPO2" data-has-per-person-pricing="" data-has-per-block-pricing="">PRODUTO 2<span class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-price">TIPO2</span></label>
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide wc-pao-addon-wrap wc-pao-addon-24177-TIPO-1">
            <a href="#" class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch" data-value="TIPO2" data-price="<span class=&quot;wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-price&quot;>TIPO2 </span>">
                <img src="image.jpg">
            </a>
            <select class="wc-pao-addon-image-swatch-select wc-pao-addon-field" name="addon-24177-PRODUTO 2">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option data-raw-price="" data-price="" data-price-type="flat_fee" value="TIPO2" data-label="TIPO2">TIPO2</option>
            </select>
        </p>
</div>```

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuigG.png
````

Comment: Not seeing a huge amount of code here, please edit your question and include the code.  Start a code block with ``` (shift ~, not ''') by itself on a line, and end the block with the same.

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: sorry, edit done